# Jquery, append mix of markup and script to div

Tags: jquery, html, append

I want to use jquery.append method to append some mix of html markup and js to the parent div.

I try following:

```
var swfString = "\u003cdiv id=\"flashGame\" style=\"color:red\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cscript type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\"\u003edocument.getElementById(\u0027flashGame\u0027).innerHTML = .......SOME LONG SCRIPT HERE.... \u003c/script\u003e";
$("swf").append(swfString);
```

So i expect it added to "swf" div, but it is not, also there is no any errors or warnings in FireBug.
The string with markup is correct JSON formatted string.
Any ideas pls.

Comment: I didnt like this statement: $("swf"), maybe i'm wrong but it must be some class  ".swf" or id "#swf" or element "div"

Comment: Yes thanks, you right i forgot to add # sign to selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "swf" is a `id` of that `div` you can do it like this:

```
$("#swf").append(swfString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give id or class attribute to swf div try below code:

HTML:

```
<div id="swf"></div>
or
<div class="swf"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#swf").append(swfString); // if id="swf"
or
$(".swf").append(swfString); // if class="swf"
```